# Syllogism proof using set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, quantifiers

$$B\subseteq C \wedge B\nsubseteq A^c \Rightarrow A\nsubseteq C^c$$

So I need to prove that $$\exists x \in A\,\ x\notin C^c$$

so far I'm up to the point where I can say that $$\exists x \in C , x \in A$$

I've noticed that if I swap the A and C around then I have my answer but what steps do I take to be able to swap it around or is the ending statement simply false?

Comment: So then is the statement false since what you stated means that i can't simply just swap the terms as they're not equivalent?

Comment: Forgive me, I was very wrong, they are equivalent. $\exists x\in X.\,x\in Y$ is the same as $\exists x(x\in X\wedge x\in Y)$, so it’s indeed equivalent to $\exists x\in Y.\,x\in X$. Equivalence doesn’t hold when $\exists$ is replaced by $\forall$.

Comment: So for any problem where i come to the conclusion that there exists an x in X  such that x is in Y i can also flip it and say that there exists an x in Y such that x is in X?

Comment: No doubt. (Can’t post such a short comment without this parenthetical, though.)

Comment: So that's a yes?

Comment: Definitely yes. In depths of formal set theory, $\exists x\in X.\,\phi$ is *defined* as $\exists x(x\in X\wedge\phi)$, so if proposition $\phi$ is $x\in Y$, by commutativity of $\wedge$ we have $\exists x(x\in Y\wedge x\in X)$, and by definition it is then $\exists x\in Y.\,x\in X$.

Comment: For users with enough rep to see it, this is a duplicate question: See [Check my answer for syllogism disproof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569733/check-my-answer-for-syllogism-disproof)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$B\subseteq C \wedge B\nsubseteq A^c$$

by the second part we have $\exists x\in B,x\notin A^c$, we can change $\notin A^c$ into $\in A$ to get $$\exists x\in B,x\in A$$from the first part of the original statement we can change $B$ to $C$ to get$$\exists x\in C,x\in A$$change the order we are looking at it to get $$\exists x\in A,x\in C$$
changing the order is okay since those statements are simply properties of $x$, there is no order to those properties, they all are just... exists you can say. it is like saying: i am a human and i am standing VS i am standing and i am a human.

we can now change $\in C$ into $\notin C^c$ to get $$\exists x\in A,x\notin C^c$$hence we get $$A\nsubseteq C^c$$

Comment: But how can you change the order to swap A and C in lines 3-4 of latex?
Edit:But there's no $$\wedge$$ there, it's just a comma, or does the comma  replace $$\wedge$$?

Comment: i edit the answer to explain it better, look at it now

Comment: @thefatone yes, comma can replace $\wedge$, when i say $\exists x\in A,x\in C$ this is equal to $\exists x: x\in A\wedge x\in C$

Comment: ok thanks so much

Comment: the property that permits us to change from $a \land b$ to $b\land a$, such that $a \land b = b\land a$ is called the ***commutative property*** (of conjunction (logical "and")). That's the property that tells us $a +b = b+a$ (commutative property of addition), that $a\cdot b = b\cdot a$ (commutative property of multiplication of real numbers), that $a \lor b = b\lor a$ (commutative property of disjuction (logical inclusive or exclusive  "or")).

Answer (score 1):

$B \subseteq C$ means: $\forall x \ (x \in B \to x \in C)$.

And $B \nsubseteq A^c$ means: $\exists x \ (x \in B \land x \notin A^c)$, i.e: $\exists x \ (x \in B \land x \in A)$.

For $(\exists x∈A)x∉C^c$, see [Restricted quantifiers](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Restricted_quantifier); it is an abbreviation for: $\exists x \ ( x∈A \land x∉C^c)$ that in turn means: $\exists x \ (x∈A \land x∈C)$.

Now we can complete the syllogism:

> $\exists x \ (x \in A \land x \in B)$,
>
> $\forall x \ (x \in B \to x \in C)$;

therefore:

> > $\exists x \ (x∈A \land x∈C)$.

Comment: How do i compute $$\exists x (x \in A \wedge x \notin C^c)$$ ? i've never seen anything like it before.

Comment: Nah, that's not the problem, i understand that x in A and x not in A compliment are the same thing.

The problem is how do i get from $$\exists x\in C :x\in A$$ to $$\exists x\in A :x\in C$$